# Jquery scrolling to above div by set value

Tags: jquery, html

I have a floating navigation bar on the top of the page so when I click of #ID links it hides the object I want to scroll to behind it.

I am using jquery for scrolling with this code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Is there a way I can scroll to slightly lower or higher than the location of the  tag by a set amount of pixels?

[Demo](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104410405/HTML%20Templates/Modern/index.html)

Note: Make sure to allow "unsafe content" in chrome since some of the jquery wont work otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `scrollTop: target.offset().top` to `scrollTop: target.offset().top + x` where x is the number you would like to add or subtract

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean

```
scrollTop: target.offset().top - 50
```

?